# Compare two svn releases (with IntelliJ or some other tool)

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

IntelliJ lets you compare a file with a different release of the same file.
That is very useful.

Is it possible for IntelliJ to compare a whole directory with a different release of the same directory?
Basically, it should list the files that are different, and then by clicking at each file it would compare that individual file as I mentioned at the beginning.
(without this option, you have to find out which files have changed, with svn log -vq | egrep '^ +[ADM]', and then ask IntelliJ to compare each individual file)

So, does IntelliJ already have this or similar functionality? how to use it?
Otherwise, is there a good tool for analyzing/comparing/merging svn releases?

ps: IntelliJ can compare whole directories with other branches; 
but I do not have a different branch here, just a different release.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-55335), please star/vote.

Comment: Voted & commented :-)